# How to make certain part of image clickable in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uiimageview, coordinates

In one of my app i am using image for the whole screen. Which can be zoomed to some extent. That image has eight different shapes(includes person,shapes,etc).What i am trying to do is i need to make certain each shape of the image is clickable. Touching each part takes to different screens.I didn't have any idea about how to achieve this. I googled it but no solution.

**1.) Is this possible by using co-ordinates(will normal image and zoomed image differ in co-ordinates? How to achieve this by using co-ordinates?**

**2.) If not what will be the best approach to achieve my goal?**

Any ideas/samples is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the imageView holding your image. And the `locationOfTouch:inView:` method to determine the coordinates of your touch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What will be the case when the image get zoomed? will this work?

Comment: I did not test it, but I think that zooming will not change the coordinates of the touch. So yes I think it will work perfectly

Comment: the tap getsture is working. But how do we know that specific part of the image is tapped. i.e if there is box in the image i need to perform some functions when the user tabbed anywhere in the box. How to do that? any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i don't understand your question. For me, that should be very simple? Just have couple of buttons which background is clear? And They are all on top of the image.

Comment: Yes you can do that but my image want to be zoomable. In that case it wont work

Answer (score 0):

Check [`UIResponder`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and the touches methods in there.  You'll probably want to hook in to something like `-touchesEnded:withEvent:` for detecting when a finger lifts off the screen.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGRect touchLocationInView = [touch locationInView:imageView];
        // Do something to check that the rect is valid
        // If valid, react to it
    }
}
```

Also, [a link to `UITouch`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer. Sorry for the late response, I just came back. How to identify the specific rect or how to create a rect for certain shape in the whole image

Comment: You would define the `rect` yourself, knowing the image ahead of time.  Maybe create a map, image name to rects, and do some searching that way.